Why is my code unable to find a file using MediaStore even though it exists in file storage?
I’m using MediaStore to store small pieces of data in file storage so the data persists even if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app. My approach is to store the data alongside a local database. When the app is reinstalled, I check if the local database is empty (indicating an uninstall), and if it is, I attempt to retrieve the data from file storage using MediaStore.
The issue is that when I save or create the file, I can successfully modify it. However, after uninstalling and reinstalling the app, I can no longer modify the file, and my code cannot locate it in storage, even though I can confirm that the file still physically exists in file storage.

The URI path used to retrieve the file is content://media/external/downloads/
Confirmed that the app has the appropriate permissions (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) where required.
Tested reading and modifying other files in the same directory to ensure MediaStore can handle those files correctly.
Logged the database status to confirm my logic correctly identifies when the local database is empty.


"Verified the file exists using a file explorer app" -- where exactly is this being stored on the device? "Double-checked the URI path used to retrieve the file via MediaStore" -- where are you getting this Uri from? Without a [mcve], it will be difficult for anyone to help you very much. However, particularly for locations like Downloads/ and Documents/, your new app installation has no rights to files created by prior installations of your app.

The URI path is content://media/external/downloads/

Your app does not have rights to arbitrary content in Downloads/, including content placed there by previous installations of your app.
